# How to synchronize indexes and repository of Apache Lucene and Solr in Clustered JBoss

Tags: solr, jboss, lucene

I have a situation, I want to run my demo Web-Application built with EJB-Hibernate into JBoss Cluter for High Availability and in my application we use Apache Solr (and one part uses Lucene as well) for text-based search.

I got the clustering information from Jboss official website, but I am not able to get any information about how to sync up solr or lucene indexes and their data repositories..?

I am sure that lot many people must have done clustering with Lucene or solr in them, please anyone point me to the correct source about it. About how to synchronize solr or lucene directories on multiple server instances of JBoss.

I have embedded solr deployment, so as Jayendra had suggested below, Solr Replication with HTTP is not possible for me. Is there any other way to do solr-replication with repeater configuration (i.e. my all nodes will act as both master as well as slave)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy/sync data repositories for Solr, you can check for [Solr Replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) which will allow you to sync data repositories across different solrs instances on different machines

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted thank you I will read on this. I have some private folders e.g. for attachements, which I want to sync up in cluster, so is there any way to that too.

Comment: Hi, I read the article, but I have embedded solr deployment, so above solr-replication with http-api won't be possible in my scenario. For embedded solr deployments is there any other way...

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CollectionDistribution you can check. But it is not actively maintained now.

Answer (score 0):

The clustering technology of JBoss and WildFly is based on the [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org/) OSS project.

Infinispan provides an highly efficient distributed storage model, and the project includes an Apache Lucene index storage layer:

- http://infinispan.org/docs/dev/user_guide/user_guide.html#integrations:lucene-directory

It should be easy to replace the Solr `Directory` with this implementation.